# Change all values of a specific key from json object

Tags: python, python-3.x

My json object:

```
"students": [
 {
    "name" : "ben",
    "hometown" : "unknown"
 },
 {
    "name" : "sam",
    "hometown" : "unknown"
  }
 ]
}
```

with this list

```
"hometowns":{California,Colorado}
```

change to this:

```
"students": [
 {
    "name" : "ben",
    "hometown" : "California"
 },
 {
    "name" : "sam",
    "hometown" : "Colorado"
  }
 ]
}
```

I need to loop and check if the `key = "hometown"` and change its value like
`students[1].hometown == hometowns[1]`.

Comment: And? What did you try? How did it go wrong? It seems like you got the general idea of how to do it. With what exactly are you struggling? Loop the students list, and replace the hometown with the following town from the list...

Answer (score 0):

First, note that your syntax is a bit off (and your towns are actually states). After correcting the syntax, we can use the `zip()` function to iterate over both lists together:

```py
hometowns = ["California", "Colorado"]

students = [{"name": "ben", "hometown": "unknown"},
            {"name": "sam", "hometown": "unknown"}]

for student, hometown in zip(students, hometowns):
    student['hometown'] = hometown
    
students
```

```
[{'name': 'ben', 'hometown': 'California'},
 {'name': 'sam', 'hometown': 'Colorado'}]
```

Comment: ohh thanks for pointing that out, I just used it for examples

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
hometowns=["California","Colorado"]
students=[{"name" : "ben",},{"name" : "sam"}]

for student,town in zip(students,hometown):
    student["hometown"]=town
```

I assumed you were trying to specify `hometowns` and `students` as variables rather than elements of a larger dictionary, which would change the syntax somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

here is an alternative simple solution if you have not learnt about `zip()` in python:

```
hometowns = ["California","Colorado"]

a = {"students": [
 {
    "name" : "ben",
    "hometown" : "unknown"
 },
 {
    "name" : "sam",
    "hometown" : "unknown"
 }
] }

num = 0
for j in a["students"]:
    j["hometown"] = hometowns[num]
    num += 1

print(a)
```

Comment: very sorry Ive edited my question, Ive tried this and got the error KeyError: 'title'

Comment: this is because "hometowns":{California,Colorado} is not a list and in you are suppose to write an key-value pair inside the dictionary {California, Colorado} or either you can also write it as a list hometowns= [California, Colorado]